# Angular 6 Material Nested Tree is not working with dynamic data

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material2

I am using `mat-tree` with `mat-nested-tree-node` in Angular 6.
What I want is to load the data dynamically when the user toggles expand icon.

Using the dynamic data example of `Flat Tree` given in [Material Examples](https://material.angular.io/components/tree/examples) I have tried to use the same concept for `Nested Tree`. This is what I have tried so far https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-naarcp

But it only shows the data which was prepopulated in the data array although in the console it is clear that data is getting updated but it never gets shown on the UI.

It recursively calls the `_getChildren` method for the nodes `parent, child1, child2, child3` because this is initial data. I am adding `My Child` in `child1` and `child3` when user expands it but the added node is never shown.

I can not add dynamic children in `_getChildren` because it gets called recursively till last node.

### Note:

I dont want to use Flat tree because it manages everything in single array and updating the single array gets really difficult in asynchronous loading of data

### Help

Is there anything I am missing or nested trees are designed to work this way?

Comment: im running into the very same issue were you able to solve this?

Comment: @Alvaromon No. I used FlatTreeControl with dynamic data as mentioned in https://material.angular.io/components/tree/examples

Comment: I have the same issue as well. I am still working on finding a way. I'll post if I find a solution

Answer (score 2):

I struggled when I implemented back when it first came out and found the UI wasnt updating because changes to an objects's properties do not get picked up by change detection. Please read through my original question and answer here. It is for a flattened tree but might save you hours of banging your head.

[Why is my angular app becoming very slow after changing the data backing a mat-tree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51100217/why-is-my-angular-app-becoming-very-slow-after-changing-the-data-backing-a-mat-t)