# Angular tree expand single node takes too much time

Tags: angular, angular-material2, expand

I am using mat tree and for expand nodes I am using below function

```
indecesArray.forEach((element,i) => { 
let t5 = performance.now(); this.treeControl.expand(this.treeControl.dataNodes[ element ]); 
let t6 = performance.now(); 
console.log("Treet at index-"+i+"took"+ (t6 - t5) + "milliseconds");
 });
```

In here indecesArray having only 2 elements and this.treeControl.dataNodes having 5000 elements. It is taking 10 seconds to expand nodes.

Is there any issue with expand function?

Comment: I am not too familiar with the tree component but 5000 elements sounds already too much in terms of UX. From performance here, is  there any additional markup in the treenodes rendered? Think if you could trim the size down e.g. by virtual scroll, filter, pagination, ...

Comment: I am having values on children level which is returned from API call. How can I implement virtual scroll on child level . Any idea?

Comment: Same question here, if u found any answer please share in here. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular Mat tree re-render performance issue takes too much time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55965653/angular-mat-tree-re-render-performance-issue-takes-too-much-time)